# My Canister ceiling light bulbs, LED 65, BR30 burn out too quickly

Tags: lighting

Have kitchen canister fixtures. The bulbs 65 watt BR30 Flood, burn out too quickly - one at a time in about 3 months. Ceiling (attic) heavily insulated

Comment: Are the can lights new or old?

Comment: 65 **actual** watts, or "65 watt replacement LED" - ie, typically 7-12 watts depending how well/poorly the thing is built?

Answer (score 3):

Heavily insulated can lights are a Bad, Bad thing for LED bulbs - LED bulbs are already compromised in their cooling ability by being forced to fit in an envelope that is similar in shape to an incandescent bulb. Stick it in an IC can fixture with no airflow and insulation all around, and it gets hot. Heat kills LEDs and heat also kills LED power supplies (what turns 120/240 VAC into DC current and voltage proper for the LED module itself.)

Given the price of LED bulbs, you are probably not saving money .vs. using incandescent bulbs that can take the heat, or somewhat more efficient halogen bulbs that LOVE the heat if you are killing a bulb avery 3 months.

A non-bulb-shaped LED retrofit module can have somewhat better cooling designed in. One of those might last longer, though I note that ones I have specify a life of 35,000 hours in IC fixtures and 50,000 in ventilated fixtures, so even there it's definitely hurting the life.

Replacing the entire fixture with a designed-from-the-ground-up LED fixture that has effective cooling built in is the best option for long LED life. If you are not going to do that, I'd suggest looking for Halogen incandescent bulbs and not killing any more LED bulbs in these fixtures.

Comment: CFL's have come a long ways color-wise these past few years. They might also prove a good replacement for overheating LED's.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Heat is not terribly kind to the ballasts (cute pile of electronics in the base of) CFLs, either. Base-up in an insulated can is very hard service for those.

Comment: Yes, there can be problems, but I've heard good things about the latest generation of spotlight style CFLs, designed for canisters. Granted, until I have one running for 6 years myself, that good word might just be marketing, but they're more energy efficient than tungsten or halogen, and far cheaper than LED.

Answer (score -2):

This maybe something for every one who is having this problems with screw in type of fixtures and this may or may not be your problem. In the socket of a can light (recessed lighting) or lamp, you have two basic parts on the inside. The socket interior, the ring of metal that makes the most connect with the lamp, is the neutral and the little metal tab, at the bottom of the socket, is the hot. The biggest thing here is that people usually tighten the lamp down to hard and the little tab at the bottom gets bent down. With the tab bent down it will not make a good connection but will light the lamp until it is to much for the lamp and it burns out. The way to fix is simple, turn of the breaker, or unplug the fixture and check to make sure it is off. With it off using a small hard flat plastic object lift the tab back out just a little(Do not Force it or it will break). With tab back in position, screw in the lamp with the tips of your fingers and stop from screwing it in to tight. Turn on the break, or plug it back in, and see if that fixed it. Another problem maybe coming from your power company. A lot of home owners in the US thinks that the power is set and it stays that way and that is not true. I have been in house where the power can go from 108v to 135v, so when you turn on the light switch or turn the knob on a lamp, you get a inrush on high voltage and the 120v lamp pops. To fix this go to a lighting supply store and ask for 130v lamps or led that should help a lot also.

Comment: So why is this a negative?  If you do not like a answer let me know why.